# Binary table containing all the combinations 00, 01, 10, 11 in every two columns

Tags: combinatorics

The following table 6x5

```
11111
10000
01000
00100
00010
00001
```

has an interesting property: if you select **any** two columns and delete the rest, the resulting table 6x2 will always contain rows 00, 01, 10, 11

I want to prove that this example has the minimal number of rows, that is **if an $m\times n$ table with 0's and 1's satisfies the property, then $m \ge n +1$**.

The only interesting case is $m=n$. (if $m<n$, add zero rows until $m=n$)

I tried induction, to no avail. (If you delete the first column of an $n \times n$ table, you receive an $n \times (n-1)$ table and so the induction proposition doesn't apply)

Also, one can try replacing 1's with 0's so long as this doesn't break the property. This idea has also led me nowhere.

At last, there is a geometric interpretation: read rows as points of $\mathbb{R}^n$, all that we want is a set of n vertices of an $n$-cube, such that projection of this set onto any 2-dimensional face is a square. Any n points must lie in a hyperplane, so this fact is kinda about sections of a cube.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "minimal". Certainly there are tables with fewer rows, fewer columns, and/or fewer entries that satisfy the property. Do you mean that if an $m\times n$ table satisfies the property, then $m$ must be at least $n + 1$?

Comment: @DavidK yes, i mean $m \ge n+1$

Comment: If that's what you mean, liaombro, then you should edit the body of your question to reflect that.

Comment: One way to approach things might be to ask, for any given number of columns $n$ (with $n\ge2$, of course), what is the minimum number of rows $m$ required so that any $m\times2$ subtable consisting of two columns has all four rows $00$, $01$, $10$, and $11$. If you compute the $m$'s for the first several values of $n$, you can check the sequence you get at the OEIS to see if there is anything already known about it. (If you're not familiar with it, OEIS = https://oeis.org -- it's the go-to website for problems like this one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a partial answer.

The following arrangement with $m=n=2^3$ is fairly obviously generalisable to any power of two:

```
  01010101
  00110011
  00001111
  00000000
  10101010
  11001100
  11110000
  11111111
```

For $n=2^3$ the result is a square matrix, but the generalization has $n=2^k$, $m=2(k+1)$, so the number of rows grows as the log of the number of columns. For example, here is the next case, with $n=16$, $m=10$:

```
  0101010101010101
  0011001100110011
  0000111100001111
  0000000011111111
  0000000000000000
  1010101010101010
  1100110011001100
  1111000011110000
  1111111100000000
  1111111111111111
```

Note that the top half of each column is the column number in binary, and the bottom half is the complement of that, and this easily allows you to show that the matrix satisfies the requirements.

I do not have proof that this is minimal, though I believe it is.
It is also not clear to me what happens in cases where the number of columns $n$ is not a power of two, and what the least value of $m-n$ is in those cases.

Comment: Wow! Really nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The claim's not true.

PICT (https://pairwise.yuuniworks.com/) gives the following counterexample, an $8 \times 8$ table.

```
11110001
00001100
10010111
01111010
10100010
01001001
01110100
10101011
```

The logic behind it is unknown to me, though.